# How to cast an `IEnumerable<Unknown T>` to `IEnumerable<Whatever>`

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on a project to filter a list in a generic way. I am retrieving an `IEnumerable<T>` at runtime but I don't know what is `T`. I need to cast the list I am retrieving to `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IEnumerable`, because I need extension methods like `ToList` and `Where`. Here is my code.

```
private IList<object> UpdateList(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] conditions)
{
    // Here I want to get the list property to update
    // The List is of List<Model1>, but of course I don't know that at runtime
    // casting it to IEnumerable<object> would give Invalid Cast Exception
    var listToModify = (IEnumerable<object>)propertyListInfoToUpdate.GetValue(model);

    foreach (var condition in conditions)
    {
        // Filter is an extension method defined below
        listToModify = listToModify.Filter(condition .Key, condition .Value);
    }

    // ToList can only be invoked on IEnumerable<T>
    return listToModify.ToList();
}



public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string propertyName, object value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)property.Member).PropertyType;
    Expression constant = Expression.Constant(value);

    if (((ConstantExpression)constant).Type != propertyType)
    { constant = Expression.Convert(constant, propertyType); }

    var equality = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equality, parameter);

    var compiled = predicate.Compile();

    // Where can only be invoked on IEnumerable<T>
    return source.Where(compiled);
}
```

Also please note that I cannot retrieve the List like this

```
((IEnumerable)propertyListInfoToUpdate.GetValue(model)).Cast<object>()
```

since it will generate the below exception in the `Filter` extention

```
ParameterExpression of type 'Model1' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'
```

Comment: This looks like a very reasonable question to me, not the kind certainly that should be downvoted without any comment.

Comment: Why don't you give `UpdateList` a generic type parameter? `UpdateList<T>`. And enter `propertyListInfoToUpdate.GetValue(model)` as parameter (which is better anyway, because now your method relies on external state).

Comment: @GertArnold The same problem will still be there, because the external caller will still don't know what is `T`. All I know is the property I need to retrieve, nothing more.

Comment: Write an extension method `CastTo<T1,T2>` which copies every properties/fields to the new type by reflection/

Comment: Then the question is: why is `propertyListInfoToUpdate.GetValue(model)` not generic? Etc.

Comment: There's too much noise in the question. What do you have, and what do you want to cast it to?

Comment: @ScottHannen pretty simple, I want to execute Linq queries on a List that I do not know it's Generic Argument except at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GetGenericArguments` and `MakeGenericMethod` to interface generic signatures.

```
private IList<object> UpdateList(KeyValuePair<string, string> conditions)
{
    var rawList = (IEnumerable)propertyListInfoToUpdate.GetValue(model);

    var listItemType = propertyListInfoToUpdate.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    var filterMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("Filter").MakeGenericMethod(genericType);

    object listToModify = rawList;
    foreach (var condition in conditions)
    {
        listToModify = filterMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { listToModify, condition.Key, condition.Value })
    }

    return ((IEnumerable)listToModify).Cast<object>().ToList();
}
```

Assuming your `propertyListInfoToUpdate` is a `PropertyInfo` and the property type is `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `Expression` at all? It's hard to understand your question without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Even if we could solve the casting question, you're still returning `IList<object>`. It's not like the consumer of the code will benefit from the casting.

And it's not really possible to solve the casting problem, at least not in the way you seem to want. A different approach would be to call the `Filter()` dynamically. In the olden days, we'd have to do this by using reflection, but the `dynamic` type gives us runtime support. You could get it to work something like this:

```
    private IList<object> UpdateList(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] conditions)
    {
        dynamic listToModify = propertyListInfoToUpdate.GetValue(model);

        foreach (var condition in conditions)
        {
            // Filter is an extension method defined below
            listToModify = Filter(listToModify, condition.Key, condition.Value);
        }

        // ToList can only be invoked on IEnumerable<T>
        return ((IEnumerable<object>)Enumerable.Cast<object>(listToModify)).ToList();
    }
```

NOTE: your original code isn't valid; I made the assumption that `conditions` is supposed to be an array, but of course if you change it to anything that has a `GetEnumerator()` method, that would be fine.

All that said, it seems to me that given the lack of a compile-time type parameter, it would be more direct to just change your `Filter()` method so that it's not generic, and so that you use `object.Equals()` to compare the property value to the condition value. You seem to be jumping through a lot of hoops to use generics, without gaining any of the compile-time benefit of generics.

Note that if all this was about was executing LINQ query methods, that could be addressed easily simply by using `Enumerable.Cast<object>()` and using `object.Equals()` directly. It's the fact that you want to use expressions to access the property value (a reasonable goal) that is complicating the issue. But even there, you can stick with `IEnumerable<object>` and just build the `object.Equals()` into your expression.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter. 1. putting aside how the question was written, I am returning an `IList<object>` because it does not matter in my logic what I return, I might even just return `IList` or `IEnumerable` but that's not the point. 2. thanks for the `dynamic` tip. 3. my bad on the array typo. 4. I need the generic on the `Filter` extension to be able to construct the expression needed and to invoke the `Where` extension method without reflection. Also I already mentioned that `Cast<object>` throws runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an expression and compiling it every time is very expensive. You should either use Reflection directly or a library like [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) (or cache the expressions). In addition, your code uses `Expression.Equal` which translates into the equality operator (`==`), which is not a good way of comparing objects. You should be using `Object.Equals`.

Here is the code using FastMember:

```
private IList<object> UpdateList(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] conditions)
{
    var listToModify = ((IEnumerable)propertyListInfoToUpdate.GetValue(model)).Cast<object>();

    foreach (var condition in conditions)
    {
        listToModify = listToModify.Where(o => Equals(ObjectAccessor.Create(o)[condition.Key], condition.Value));
    }

    return listToModify.ToList();
}
```

Side note - your `Filter` method doesn't really need generics. It can be changed to accept and return an `IEnumerable<object>` by tweaking the expression, which also would've solved your problem.